# Responsive Design Challenge: Elements Misaligned on Mobile View

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I'm encountering an issue with responsive design where certain elements are misaligned when viewed on mobile devices. Despite using media queries and flexible layouts, the problem persists.

I've implemented media queries to adjust styles for smaller screens, tested different viewport settings, and inspected the layout using responsive design tools.
I expect the elements to align correctly and maintain a responsive layout on various mobile devices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77558330/edit) your question to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. Also, please paste your code in the question using code blocks/snippets for formatting, instead of links or images. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).